# Store ASCII codes in mysql DB

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, character-encoding

I need to store in a MySQL database table ASCII character codes like [this](http://vnamedia.net/facebook-special-symbols-emoticons-ascii-art-shapes.html#axzz1nsvwJBd0) for example (★⋰⋱★⋰⋱★⋰⋱★⋰⋱★)
Should I manipulate the data before saving to my db (using javascript) 
in order to be stored as html codes (&heart;) or should I change the type the data is stored and MySQL will handle everything? (Utf-8)

Comment: Absolutely UTF-8. There's usually no need for HTML entities any more nowadays

Comment: Even thought disk space is cheap, it's still far easier to store a single 1 or 2 byte character than a full 7-byte text entity.

Comment: Note that these aren't *ASCII* characters. The term ASCII is often abused, and it matters in this sort of context.

Comment: You should use UTF-8 (general_ci) instead of unicode. Check some useful info here: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748

Comment: @JonSkeet Could you please tell me how those characters are called, in order to use them properly... for future reference?

Comment: @paokg4: Ironically, "non-ASCII" is the best starting place probably :) More usefully, you'd just look up the Unicode code points (on http://unicode.org/charts) - these days almost everything is in terms of some encoded form of Unicode.

Comment: Or you can paste them into the search field at http://unicodelookup.com/ which will tell you their Unicode names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your database field must be encoded in ASCII, I would definitely store those esoteric characters as say `&heart;` as you said because ASCII certainly does not extend to those characters (ASCII uses only 7 bits to store character data).

Nonetheless, I would recommend using UTF-8 for your database field. UTF-8 allows for a far wider range of characters.

Comment: There was a post on here that I saw yesterday of someone doing the same thing but with iOS emoticons. UTF-8 would only extend so far and some of them needed UTF-16. However since it is just ASCII chars you should be good with UTF-8

Comment: @Computer, David - the OP is clearly confusing "ASCII" with "plain text". He wants to store plain text with Unicode characters, and the way to go for that is definitely UTF-8 unless it's 4-byte characters which mySQL can't store

Comment: Good points. Ok, so UTF-8 and even UTF-16 if need be are the way to go :)